# How to create a popup page using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I'm new in web develop. I want to realize a function that when I click the link "click to see sample colors", it will popup a page like the picture to show all my sample colors. But I don't know what kind of technics to use to do it. I have search on w3schools. But the popup window or popup boxes using javaScript is not what I want.

Could you help me to realize the effect using a simple way?

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I understand what you're saying. Here is a codepen example that uses a CSS modal box instead. Check it out:

http://codepen.io/ShadyAlzayat/pen/LEDJg

The modal code is as follows:

```
.modal {
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
text-align: left;
background: rgba(0,0,0, .9);
transition: opacity .25s ease;
}

.modal__bg {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-state {
display: none;
}

.modal-state:checked + .modal {
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
}

.modal-state:checked + .modal .modal__inner {
top: 0;
}

.modal__inner {
transition: top .25s ease;
position: absolute;
top: -20%;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 50%;
margin: auto;
overflow: auto;
background: #fff;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 1em 2em;
height: 50%;
}

.modal__close {
position: absolute;
right: 1em;
top: 1em;
width: 1.1em;
height: 1.1em;
cursor: pointer;
}

.modal__close:after,
.modal__close:before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
width: 2px;
height: 1.5em;
background: #ccc;
display: block;
transform: rotate(45deg);
left: 50%;
margin: -3px 0 0 -1px;
top: 0;
}

.modal__close:hover:after,
.modal__close:hover:before {
background: #aaa;
}

.modal__close:before {
transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

.modal__inner {
width: 90%;
height: 90%;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) has a [nice modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-examples) screen for this.

Here is a little example. Don't forget to include bootstrap, how to do this is of course to be found on the [Bootstrap homepage](http://getbootstrap.com/).

To create a modal, just place this somewhere in your body:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">

    <div class="modal-header">
        <!-- Title here -->
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- Content here -->
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And define a button like this:

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch Modal</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you've already have the page that contains the popup page. For show it like a popup, just create a link in HTML with `<a></a>` for call a function that opens the popup. Also you don't need to use jQuery; you can use the `open()` method.

You need to write a code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

var style = "status=no, menubar=no, toolbar=no scrollbars=no";

function popup(link)
{
  window.open(link, "", style);
}
//-->
</script>

<a href="javascript:popup('myPage.html')">My link</a>
```

The `style` variable defines the style of a classical popup. You can see the complete documentation of `open()` method on:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp